# Desktop Icons dissapearing and windows not opening up

Tags: nautilus

This is my third time asking this question. As soon as I log in desktop icons disappear and none of the windows open up. If they open up the close down immediately. Right after that my computer freezes up. Seems like an error with Nautilus. This has made working on the laptop really impossible. I don't Know the solution to this. Please help ASAP. It's a recurring problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that is a Nautilus/Files error, try to restart it with the following command:

nautilus -q